# How to map vector into nearest point in another vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Assume I have a vector `a` of length `N` and another vector `b = [-3 -1 1 3]`, is there any efficient way to map each element of `a` to its nearest (Euclidean distance) element in `b`. I do not want to use loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` to compute the difference between every element in the two vectors. This will return a `numel(a) x numel(b)` matrix of differences. We can then take the absolute value and find the column at which the smallest differences occurs for each element in `a` (using the second output of `min`). If you want the actual *value* of `b` that is closest to each element in `a`, you can then use the second output of `min` to index into `b`.

```
a = linspace(-3, 3, 8);
b = [-3 -1 1 3];

[~, closest] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, a(:), b(:).')), [], 2);
%     1     1     2     2     3     3     4     4

b_for_each_a = b(closest);
%    -3    -3    -1    -1     1     1     3     3
```

Your example is in one-dimension so Euclidean distance doesn't actually matter apart from using the absolute value of the distance.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. I cannot accept it as an answer as I do not have enough points. Please do if you can.

Comment: Okay. Will do in 4 min. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Also `[~, closest] = pdist2(b(:), a(:), 'euclidean', 'Smallest', 1); b_for_each_a = b(closest);`